# Problems with backslashes in hyperlinks in Emacs org-mode on Windows

Tags: org-mode, microsoft-windows, hyperlinks

I'm struggling again with `Emacs 24.4` and `org-mode` (version 8.3beta (release_8.3beta-1013-g187dae`` @ c:/Users/mbec.POLYWBR/Documents/sorga/org-mode/org_current/lisp/)

I'm having problem with paths like that:

`[[file+sys:\\servername.domain.de\dir\]]`

which produce the error **"No such file c:/servername.domain.de/dir/"**

So org-mode seems to replace \ by / and then create a local path on my hard disk c: instead of resolving the path to the network server correctly.

Does anyone else work on Windows in a Windows Server network environment with similar paths and can tell me how to set things up correctly?

*Remark:* **in dired+ it works well**:
if I launch `M-x RET dired` and then paste a path like `\\server.domain.de\dir1\dir2` , `dired` seems to convert it to `//server.domain.de/dir1/dir2`and opens the right directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After installing `Emacs 24.5.1` the problem did not occur any more.

It works with `org-mode 8.2.10` as well as with the current beta `8.3 beta` (daily snapshot from today)

Answer (score 1):

I can't test this, but try

`[[file+sys:\\\\servername.domain.de\dir\]]`

or

`[[file+sys:\\\\servername.domain.de\\dir\\]]`

Comment: thanks, I'm currently not at the Windows machine, but I'll try next week

Comment: no, this does not help either. :-(